# xmpp ejabberd: to many unacked stanzas

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I'm running an ejabberd-server. Some weeks it worked really nice. But now I'm getting always the error: Stream closed by us: Too many unacked stanzas (policy-violation).
I don't know, why I'm getting the error, because I just connected as usual to the server from a mobile client. How can I delete unacked stanzas for using the ejabberd server like before?
Thanks in advance
yajo10

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know where else I could ask.

Comment: Thank's. But I found out that the page https://docs.ejabberd.im/ with the link 'Ask questions' references to stackoverflow. So may It's the correct one?

Answer (score 1):

Solved at [Github](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/2615)

The parameter max_ack_queue was set to 70 but the normal value is 5000